# DataStage Transformer stage how to check if explicit text is in the column's values

Tags: datastage

Currently, I am using the Count function inside a Transformer stage in a parallel job to check if the values of 1 Stage Variable (**StageVar**) contain some explicit value then give another column (**Code**) some values.


There's so many **Code** to check in the **StageVar** but I'll just take the '**D**' code for example:

```
If the StageVar contains 'DEBT' (and only 'DEBT', not any other string like 'DEBTOR' or 'ODEBT', etc) in its value, the Code column for that row will have the 'D' code.
```

Here's the code that I use in the Code column's derivation:

```
If Count(StageVar, 'DEBT') > 0 Then 'D' Else SetNull()
```

It succeeded in giving the code '**D**' to which row that the **StageVar** contains the '**DEBT**' string. But the problem is the content of the **StageVar** is not always having the '**DEBT**' string that stands alone.


There're some cases that the **StageVar** may contain the '**DEBTOR**' like 'PAY **DEBTOR** STATEMENT IN NOVEMBER' or '**ODEBT**' like 'PAYMENT **ODEBT** FOR NOVEMBER', which I'll ignore and not giving the '**D**' code for the **Code** column.


But the above code also giving the '**D**' code for them.
Do you guys have any idea how to fix this inside the Transformer stage itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that StageVar has a leading space and a trailing space.  For example `" NATIONAL DEBT IS OUT OF CONTROL "`
You could use Count() function, but Index() is probably more what you want. Also encase your search string in space characters.

```
If Count(StageVar, " DEBT ") > 0 Then "D" Else SetNull()

If Index(StageVar, " DEBT ", 1) > 0 Then "D" Else SetNull()
```

Index() stops searching as soon as it finds the first occurrence.  Count() must perforce search to the end of StageVar.

Comment: Thank you sir, your logic is excellent. I fixed the code as you said and it worked like a charm. And also thank you for your recommendation on using Index instead of Count function in this case, I'll definitely use that.